# Error reading entity from input stream - using Jackson

Tags: java, jackson

I need to call a API that return the following in JSON format and convert them into JAVA object:

```
GET /api/myimpl/?ids=5,12

HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

[
    {
        "id": "A1",
        "impl": "HeatSmart"
    },
    {
        "id": "B2",
        "impl": "My String"
    }
]
```

I have the following class:

```
public class QueryStrings {
    private String id;
    private String impl;

    public QueryStrings() {
    }

    public QueryStrings(String id, String impl) {
        this.id = id;
        this.impl = impl;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getImpl() {
        return impl;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setImpl(String impl) {
        this.impl = impl;
    }
}
```

In my codes, I do the following:

```
client = ClientBuilder.newClient().register(JacksonFeature.class);
Response clientResponse = client.target(myURL)
        .queryParam("ids", "5,12")
        .request()
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
        .get();
QueryStrings jsonResponse = clientResponse.readEntity(QueryStrings.class);
```

The clientResponse returns status OK. However, the last line return error below when I am trying to get the json into the object I want:

```
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Error reading entity from input stream.
```

What is missing from my codes?

Comment: As I understood, HTTP response contains array  of `QueryStrings`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `api` return array of `QueryStrings`, so you can use `GenericType` in `readEntity`

```
List<QueryStrings> results = response.readEntity(new GenericType<List<QueryStrings>>(){});
```